# Clicking Menu item then update div content with php page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a logged_in.php page where you are automatically redirected to when the login succeeds. This page has a sidebar included. The menu items in the sidebar can be clicked, and I want to keep the sidebar from reloading when clicking a link. Insteed, the div right from the sidebar should be filled with page.php for example.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know how, can you send me a link of a page where this is explained? I am new to jQuery.

Comment: Hope my answer is helpful below. But in general, I think the SO community expects askers to do a modicum of research before asking their questions. The same documentation I provide below would have been easily available if you had done a Google search for "jquery load part of a page".

Comment: Thanks very much. I will do better research the next time, but compared to other similar answers on similar questions your answer is much more clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a simple usage of AJAX, and Jquery makes this easy. The full documentation for one solution can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Here's a rough sketch of what I would try. This is *by far* not the only way to do this, but it's relatively convenient.

1. The DIV that you want text to load into, should be given an id, maybe like this: id='ajaxContent' . So the div HTML would look like this: `<div id='ajaxContent'></div>`
2. Each link in the sidebar that you want to "trigger" the div to reload, should have a common class, maybe: class='ajaxTrigger' .
3. Give each link a separate attribute, maybe like this: load='page1.php' . So the first link would look something like this: `<a class='ajaxTrigger' load='page1.php'>Page 1</a>`
4. Write a Jquery listener that detects when the user clicks on a link, and redirects them to the appropriate page. Maybe like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxTrigger').click(function(){
    var pageName = $(this).attr('load');
    $('#ajaxContent').load('/path/to/page/'+pageName);
  });
});
```

There's nothing magical about pageName in the code above. It's just a string, specified by you in the link tag, that becomes part of the URL to load. For each link, simply adjust the *load* attribute to point to a different page. If pages are in different subfolders, you can put slashes in there too.

Comment: I already have a class in the <a> from the css file, so now it gets a bit messed up. How can I change this?

Comment: Hi @bashoogzaad, this question is way too vague (and a bit off topic) for me to be able to answer usefully here. When you have a problem, please take the time to describe your situation and your problem more thoroughly and with examples. Users who find your questions clear and thorough will be more willing and able to provide helpful responses.